# JPA query for day ignoring the time

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Let say you have a class with a java.util.Date field. Maybe a To do class or an Event planner class.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;
```

This will map to a datetime column in MySQL.

There are use cases when you want to know precisely when this Event occurs. "What is scheduled for Aug 11, 2011 at 8 PM?"

Sometimes you just want to know which events are planned for a specific date. "What is scheduled for August 11, 2011?"

If your JPAQL is:

```
SELECT blah blah etc. WHERE ti.startTime = :d1
```

and the parameter is a java.util.Date instance:

```
query.setParameter("d1", date, TemporalType.DATE);
```

your results will be restricted by the date but ***also the time.***

This is such a common use case that I'm surprised that there is no simple way to do this even in JPA 2.0.

I'd rather not use a vendor specific hack nor play around with strings/substrings.

How have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm a little late, but I've found a way to do this.
I was using a jpql like this:

```
select s from S s where date(s.someDate) = :param
```

And I set the param with:

```
query.setParameter("param", param, TemporalType.DATE);
```

The way I've found to do this with Criteria Query was:

```
builder.equal(
 builder.function("date", Date.class, root.get(S_.someDate)), 
 param
);
```

At least, with MySql it works.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 6):

```
select ... where ti.startTime >= :theDay and ti.startTime < :theNextDay
```

is a relatively easy solution to implement, and works on any JPA implementation.

Hibernate also allows adding functions to a dialect, in order to generate custom SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's almost what I'm doing: but I'm using BETWEEN. It works but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: If you have an index on the startTime, it must be pretty efficient. Using a SQL function to extract the date part would need an index on the function to be efficient. Note that between is inclusive: >= and <= rather than >= and <.